# Laravel 4.2 Move To A New Server Redirect Problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hello I am having some issues moving a Laravel website from one server to another. Everything appears to be working correctly but when I try to login to the website it will not redirect to any other page than the login page.

I am not getting any errors.

I am using version 4.2.

I am new to Laravel and wondering if anyone could help me out?

Thanks,

Comment: So the previous website worked 100%, and you moving it to new server without touching any code?

Comment: Did you check laravel error log or php error log?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to provide more information, but my guess is that you actually do not did not create any users in your current server and this is why your old user credentials do not work. If you don't have access to the database ssh into your server and cd into your project, then run following:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Followed by

```
App\User::all();
```

And check if it actually returns any user, if no, you don't have any users, you can do following to quickly create one:

```
// Run this in your php artisan:tinker session
App\User::create([
   'name' => 'Jon Doe',
   'email' => 'jon@doe.com',
   'password' => bcrypt('password') 
]);
```

That will create a user, if you have done that successfully try to log in to your website using those credentials. If that whole process fails you need to check or provide us your logs.

Laravel logs are located here:

> appname/storage/logs/laravel.log